# Как комментировать запись от имени группы VK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
vk.method('wall.createComment', {'owner_id': myid, 'post_id': idpost, 'from_group': idgroup, 'message': 'Test'})
```

- `myid` - ид моей страницы, на которой находится запись
- `idpost` - ид поста(под вопросом правильности)
- `idgroup` - ид группы, от имени которой нужно отправить комментарий(я в ней создатель, ключ доступа - проставлены все галочки, также, как и в longpoll)

Ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: could not access to this community
```

Возможно у меня ошибка в том, что ид поста получил неправильно, поэтому, по возможности, прикрепите к ответу то, как можно его получить

Comment: Получить id поста можно по-разному, уточните как вы сейчас получаете его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете vk_api. Все методы и параметры соответствуют документации. Есть возможность, что прав вашего токена не хватает

```
import vk_api
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен вашей группы')
api = vk_session.get_api()
api.wall.createComment(owner_id='ID куда постить',
                       post_id='ID поста',
                       from_group='ID вашей группы (положительный)',
                       message='Комментарий')
```

Если сомневаетесь в правильности входных данных можете мануально их проверить.

Группы `vk.com/club{owner_id}`

Пост `vk.com/wall{owner_id}_{post_id}`